# Flutter can't build or run - no Linux no Android app - Linux host (Gentoo machine) - permission problems

Tags: android, linux, flutter, gradle, build-error

TLDR: build toolchain not worked even it said it works. To find solution read attached solution.

I've noticed problems with `flutter 3.3.{5..7}` - first encounter for me.
I set up Android Studio and Flutter for it and every check printed everything is OK (I don't need Chrome so it's really OK):

```
flutter doctor -v
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.3.7, on Gentoo Linux 5.19.8-gentoo-systemd, locale cs_CZ.UTF-8)
    • Flutter version 3.3.7 on channel stable at /opt/flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision e99c9c7cd9 (6 days ago), 2022-11-01 16:59:00 -0700
    • Engine revision 857bd6b74c
    • Dart version 2.18.4
    • DevTools version 2.15.0

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 31.0.0)
    • Android SDK at /mnt/HDD4/FREE/android/android
    • Platform android-31, build-tools 31.0.0
    • ANDROID_HOME = /mnt/HDD4/FREE/android/android
    • Java binary at: /opt/android-studio/jre/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.13+0-b1751.21-8125866)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✗] Chrome - develop for the web (Cannot find Chrome executable at google-chrome)
    ! Cannot find Chrome. Try setting CHROME_EXECUTABLE to a Chrome executable.

[✓] Linux toolchain - develop for Linux desktop
    • clang version 15.0.3
    • cmake version 3.24.2
    • ninja version 1.11.1
    • pkg-config version 1.8.0

[✓] Android Studio (version 2021.3)
    • Android Studio at /opt/android-studio
    • Flutter plugin version 70.2.3
    • Dart plugin version 213.7433
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.13+0-b1751.21-8125866)

[✓] Connected device (1 available)
    • Linux (desktop) • linux • linux-x64 • Gentoo Linux 5.19.8-gentoo-systemd

[✓] HTTP Host Availability
    • All required HTTP hosts are available

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.
```

But when tried to run it:

```
Building flutter tool...
[  +51 ms] executing: uname -m
[  +23 ms] Exit code 0 from: uname -m
[        ] x86_64
[   +3 ms] executing: [/opt/flutter/] git -c log.showSignature=false log -n 1 --pretty=format:%H
[   +4 ms] Exit code 0 from: git -c log.showSignature=false log -n 1 --pretty=format:%H
[        ] e99c9c7cd9f6c0b2f8ae6e3ebfd585239f5568f4
[        ] executing: [/opt/flutter/] git tag --points-at e99c9c7cd9f6c0b2f8ae6e3ebfd585239f5568f4
[   +9 ms] Exit code 0 from: git tag --points-at e99c9c7cd9f6c0b2f8ae6e3ebfd585239f5568f4
[        ] 3.3.7
[  +35 ms] executing: [/opt/flutter/] git rev-parse --abbrev-ref --symbolic @{upstream}
[   +4 ms] Exit code 0 from: git rev-parse --abbrev-ref --symbolic @{upstream}
[        ] origin/stable
[        ] executing: [/opt/flutter/] git ls-remote --get-url origin
[   +3 ms] Exit code 0 from: git ls-remote --get-url origin
[        ] https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
[  +26 ms] executing: [/opt/flutter/] git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD
[   +4 ms] Exit code 0 from: git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD
[        ] stable
[  +41 ms] Artifact Instance of 'AndroidGenSnapshotArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'AndroidInternalBuildArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'IOSEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'FlutterWebSdk' is not required, skipping update.
[   +2 ms] Artifact Instance of 'WindowsEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'MacOSEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'LinuxEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'LinuxFuchsiaSDKArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'MacOSFuchsiaSDKArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'FlutterRunnerSDKArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'FlutterRunnerDebugSymbols' is not required, skipping update.
[  +43 ms] Artifact Instance of 'AndroidGenSnapshotArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'AndroidInternalBuildArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'IOSEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'FlutterWebSdk' is not required, skipping update.
[   +1 ms] Artifact Instance of 'WindowsEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'MacOSEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[   +1 ms] Artifact Instance of 'LinuxFuchsiaSDKArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'MacOSFuchsiaSDKArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'FlutterRunnerSDKArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'FlutterRunnerDebugSymbols' is not required, skipping update.
[  +64 ms] Skipping pub get: version match.
[ +112 ms] Generating /home/user/AndroidStudioProjects/project/testik/android/app/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java
[{"event":"daemon.connected","params":{"version":"0.6.1","pid":519646}}]
[{"event":"app.start","params":{"appId":"e7bd3d3c-19a8-430b-b797-ab0387c6cbb2","deviceId":"linux","directory":"/home/user/AndroidStudioProjects/project/testik","supportsRestart":true,"launchMode":"run"}}]
[  +67 ms] Initializing file store
[   +6 ms] Skipping target: gen_localizations
[   +4 ms] gen_dart_plugin_registrant: Starting due to {InvalidatedReasonKind.inputChanged: The following inputs have updated contents: /home/user/AndroidStudioProjects/project/testik/.dart_tool/package_config_subset}
[  +17 ms] gen_dart_plugin_registrant: Complete
[   +1 ms] Skipping target: _composite
[   +1 ms] complete
[   +5 ms] Launching lib/main.dart on Linux in debug mode...
[   +3 ms] /opt/flutter/bin/cache/dart-sdk/bin/dart --disable-dart-dev /opt/flutter/bin/cache/dart-sdk/bin/snapshots/frontend_server.dart.snapshot --sdk-root /opt/flutter/bin/cache/artifacts/engine/common/flutter_patched_sdk/ --incremental --target=flutter --debugger-module-names --experimental-emit-debug-metadata -Dflutter.inspector.structuredErrors=true -DFLUTTER_WEB_AUTO_DETECT=true --output-dill /tmp/flutter_tools.HUPAAR/flutter_tool.URKIDD/app.dill --packages /home/user/AndroidStudioProjects/project/testik/.dart_tool/package_config.json -Ddart.vm.profile=false -Ddart.vm.product=false --enable-asserts --track-widget-creation --filesystem-scheme org-dartlang-root --initialize-from-dill build/4f2a58af27abc49ecf55570043bbf938.cache.dill.track.dill --verbosity=error --enable-experiment=alternative-invalidation-strategy
Building Linux application...
[{"event":"app.progress","params":{"appId":"e7bd3d3c-19a8-430b-b797-ab0387c6cbb2","id":"0","progressId":null,"message":"Building Linux application...","finished":false}}]
[  +36 ms] <- compile package:testik/main.dart
[   +5 ms] executing: [build/linux/x64/debug/] cmake -G Ninja -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug -DFLUTTER_TARGET_PLATFORM=linux-x64 /home/user/AndroidStudioProjects/project/testik/linux
[  +40 ms] -- Configuring done
[   +6 ms] -- Generating done
[  +10 ms] -- Build files have been written to: /home/user/AndroidStudioProjects/project/testik/build/linux/x64/debug
[   +9 ms] executing: ninja -C build/linux/x64/debug install
[   +8 ms] ninja: Entering directory `build/linux/x64/debug'
[  +60 ms] [1/5] Generating /home/user/AndroidStudioProjects/project/testik/linux/flutter/ephemeral/libflutter_linux_gtk.so, /home/user/AndroidStudioProjects/project/testik/linux/flutter/ephemeral/flutter_linux/fl_basic_message_channel.h, /home/user/AndroidStudioProjects/project/testik/linux/flutter/ephemeral/flutter_linux/fl_binary_codec.h, /home/user/AndroidStudioProjects/project/testik/linux/flutter/ephemeral/flutter_linux/fl_binary_messenger.h, /home/user/AndroidStudioProjects/project/testik/linux/flutter/ephemeral/flutter_linux/fl_dart_project.h, /home/user/AndroidStudioProjects/project/testik/linux/flutter/ephemeral/flutter_linux/fl_engine.h, /home/user/AndroidStudioProjects/project/testik/linux/flutter/ephemeral/flutter_linux/fl_json_message_codec.h, /home/user/AndroidStudioProjects/project/testik/linux/flutter/ephemeral/flutter_linux/fl_json_method_codec.h, /home/user/AndroidStudioProjects/project/testik/linux/flutter/ephemeral/flutter_linux/fl_message_codec.h, /home/user/AndroidStudioProjects/project/testik/linux/flutter/ephemeral/flutter_linux/fl_method_call.h, /home/user/AndroidStudioProjects/project/testik/linux/flutter/ephemeral/flutter_linux/fl_method_channel.h, /home/user/AndroidStudioProjects/project/testik/linux/flutter/ephemeral/flutter_linux/fl_method_codec.h, /home/user/AndroidStudioProjects/project/testik/linux/flutter/ephemeral/flutter_linux/fl_method_response.h, /home/user/AndroidStudioProjects/project/testik/linux/flutter/ephemeral/flutter_linux/fl_plugin_registrar.h, /home/user/AndroidStudioProjects/project/testik/linux/flutter/ephemeral/flutter_linux/fl_plugin_registry.h, /home/user/AndroidStudioProjects/project/testik/linux/flutter/ephemeral/flutter_linux/fl_standard_message_codec.h, /home/user/AndroidStudioProjects/project/testik/linux/flutter/ephemeral/flutter_linux/fl_standard_method_codec.h, /home/user/AndroidStudioProjects/project/testik/linux/flutter/ephemeral/flutter_linux/fl_string_codec.h, /home/user/AndroidStudioProjects/project/testik/linux/flutter/ephemeral/flutter_linux/fl_value.h, /home/user/AndroidStudioProjects/project/testik/linux/flutter/ephemeral/flutter_linux/fl_view.h, /home/user/AndroidStudioProjects/project/testik/linux/flutter/ephemeral/flutter_linux/flutter_linux.h, _phony_
[   +5 ms] FAILED: /home/user/AndroidStudioProjects/project/testik/linux/flutter/ephemeral/libflutter_linux_gtk.so /home/user/AndroidStudioProjects/project/testik/linux/flutter/ephemeral/flutter_linux/fl_basic_message_channel.h /home/user/AndroidStudioProjects/project/testik/linux/flutter/ephemeral/flutter_linux/fl_binary_codec.h /home/user/AndroidStudioProjects/project/testik/linux/flutter/ephemeral/flutter_linux/fl_binary_messenger.h /home/user/AndroidStudioProjects/project/testik/linux/flutter/ephemeral/flutter_linux/fl_dart_project.h /home/user/AndroidStudioProjects/project/testik/linux/flutter/ephemeral/flutter_linux/fl_engine.h /home/user/AndroidStudioProjects/project/testik/linux/flutter/ephemeral/flutter_linux/fl_json_message_codec.h /home/user/AndroidStudioProjects/project/testik/linux/flutter/ephemeral/flutter_linux/fl_json_method_codec.h /home/user/AndroidStudioProjects/project/testik/linux/flutter/ephemeral/flutter_linux/fl_message_codec.h /home/user/AndroidStudioProjects/project/testik/linux/flutter/ephemeral/flutter_linux/fl_method_call.h /home/user/AndroidStudioProjects/project/testik/linux/flutter/ephemeral/flutter_linux/fl_method_channel.h /home/user/AndroidStudioProjects/project/testik/linux/flutter/ephemeral/flutter_linux/fl_method_codec.h /home/user/AndroidStudioProjects/project/testik/linux/flutter/ephemeral/flutter_linux/fl_method_response.h /home/user/AndroidStudioProjects/project/testik/linux/flutter/ephemeral/flutter_linux/fl_plugin_registrar.h /home/user/AndroidStudioProjects/project/testik/linux/flutter/ephemeral/flutter_linux/fl_plugin_registry.h /home/user/AndroidStudioProjects/project/testik/linux/flutter/ephemeral/flutter_linux/fl_standard_message_codec.h /home/user/AndroidStudioProjects/project/testik/linux/flutter/ephemeral/flutter_linux/fl_standard_method_codec.h /home/user/AndroidStudioProjects/project/testik/linux/flutter/ephemeral/flutter_linux/fl_string_codec.h /home/user/AndroidStudioProjects/project/testik/linux/flutter/ephemeral/flutter_linux/fl_value.h /home/user/AndroidStudioProjects/project/testik/linux/flutter/ephemeral/flutter_linux/fl_view.h /home/user/AndroidStudioProjects/project/testik/linux/flutter/ephemeral/flutter_linux/flutter_linux.h flutter/_phony_ /home/user/AndroidStudioProjects/project/testik/build/linux/x64/debug/flutter/_phony_ 
[        ] cd /home/user/AndroidStudioProjects/project/testik/build/linux/x64/debug/flutter && /usr/bin/cmake -E env FLUTTER_ROOT=/opt/flutter PROJECT_DIR=/home/user/AndroidStudioProjects/project/testik DART_DEFINES=Zmx1dHRlci5pbnNwZWN0b3Iuc3RydWN0dXJlZEVycm9ycz10cnVl,RkxVVFRFUl9XRUJfQVVUT19ERVRFQ1Q9dHJ1ZQ== DART_OBFUSCATION=false TRACK_WIDGET_CREATION=true TREE_SHAKE_ICONS=false PACKAGE_CONFIG=/home/user/AndroidStudioProjects/project/testik/.dart_tool/package_config.json FLUTTER_TARGET=/home/user/AndroidStudioProjects/project/testik/lib/main.dart /opt/flutter/packages/flutter_tools/bin/tool_backend.sh linux-x64 Debug
[        ] Permission denied
[        ] ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
[{"event":"app.progress","params":{"appId":"e7bd3d3c-19a8-430b-b797-ab0387c6cbb2","id":"0","progressId":null,"finished":true}}]
[ +660 ms] Exception: Build process failed
[   +2 ms] 
           #0      throwToolExit (package:flutter_tools/src/base/common.dart:10:3)
           #1      RunCommand.runCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/commands/run.dart:615:9)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #2      FlutterCommand.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command.dart:1209:27)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #3      AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:19)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #4      CommandRunner.runCommand (package:args/command_runner.dart:209:13)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #5      FlutterCommandRunner.runCommand.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command_runner.dart:281:9)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #6      AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:19)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #7      FlutterCommandRunner.runCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command_runner.dart:229:5)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #8      run.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/runner.dart:62:9)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #9      AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:19)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #10     main (package:flutter_tools/executable.dart:91:3)
           <asynchronous suspension>


[{"event":"app.stop","params":{"appId":"e7bd3d3c-19a8-430b-b797-ab0387c6cbb2"}}]
[   +9 ms] "flutter run" took 1 203ms.
[   +1 ms] Running shutdown hooks
[        ] Shutdown hooks complete
[{"id":0,"error":"app 'e7bd3d3c-19a8-430b-b797-ab0387c6cbb2' not found","trace":"#0      AppDomain.stop (package:flutter_tools/src/commands/daemon.dart:764:7)\n#1      Domain.handleCommand.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/commands/daemon.dart:274:35)\n#2      new Future.sync (dart:async/future.dart:302:31)\n#3      Domain.handleCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/commands/daemon.dart:272:5)\n#4      Daemon._handleRequest (package:flutter_tools/src/commands/daemon.dart:224:27)\n#5      _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1399:47)\n#6      _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1300:19)\n#7      _CustomZone.runUnaryGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:1209:7)\n#8      _BufferingStreamSubscription._sendData (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:339:11)\n#9      _DelayedData.perform (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:515:14)\n#10     _PendingEvents.handleNext (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:620:11)\n#11     _PendingEvents.schedule.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:591:7)\n#12     _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1383:47)\n#13     _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1293:19)\n#14     _CustomZone.runGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:1201:7)\n#15     _CustomZone.bindCallbackGuarded.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/zone.dart:1241:23)\n#16     _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1391:13)\n#17     _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1293:19)\n#18     _CustomZone.runGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:1201:7)\n#19     _CustomZone.bindCallbackGuarded.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/zone.dart:1241:23)\n#20     _microtaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:40:21)\n#21     _startMicrotaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:49:5)\n#22     _runPendingImmediateCallback (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:122:13)\n#23     _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:193:5)\n"}]
[   +3 ms] exiting with code 1
```

Even Android APP didn't run:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
[   +4 ms] * Where:
[        ] Script '/opt/flutter/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle' line: 1159
```

full log:
https://bugs.gentoo.org/attachment.cgi?id=827085

Answer (score 0):

It is totally permission problem in Flutter installation. There are some scripts and executables that aren't allowed to run by default.

To solve this just make them executable:

```bash
cd /opt/flutter/packages/flutter_tools/bin
chmod a+x *.sh
cd /opt/flutter/bin/cache/artifacts/engine/linux-x64/
chmod a+x impellerc
```

(for other systems there are *.bat in bin folder I don't care about Windows this time, installation folder is at another path - you know)

After this little steps It's alive :D